# How to Stop Bad Edits From a User

Tags: discussion, editing

Often times I will notice the same user repeatedly submitting, at least what I consider to be, bad edits such as radically changing the question or just performing some minor edit like fixing a typo or two. Is there some way to try to inform a particular user about the guidelines for making edits to try to mitigate the bad serial editing? If not, would a featured like this be beneficial?

Comment: If user is under 2K, reject their edit suggestions, this will [trigger temporary ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/edit-ban/info "details here"). I had such a ban [once in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148480/165773), it was quite educative. Over 2K, post at meta, or in chat, or contact mods

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this feature does exist. It involves leaving a comment under one of the abused posts that describes the problem and addresses the user responsible using his name prefixed by the @-symbol. Example:

> @GlennNelson: please don't edit pictures of your dog into every post you read. She's a very nice dog I'm sure, but this is not how we indicate that we've read posts here on Stack Exchange.

If that doesn't work, you can flag for a moderator's attention - they'll review the situation and take appropriate action.

#### Related:

- [The Great Edit Wars](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/)
- [In Defense of Editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)

Comment: So that will inform them in their SE notifications that you've mentioned them?

Comment: Yes, if they appear as an author in the revision history they'll be notified.